# Changing data in div JS

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I would like my `div` named ***"blok"*** to clean his inside and then show an other elements using `innerHTML`, but it always comes back to first look which is in `strona_logowanie()`.

```
<head>
    <title>Fikcyjne konto bankowe</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function login() {
            var id = formularz.id.value;
            var pass = formularz.pass.value;

            if (id=="123") {
                if (pass=="321") {
                    strona_saldo();
                }
            }
        }

        function strona_saldo() {
            var zmienna2 = "<table bgcolor='#99CC99' width='800' border='5' cellpadding='10' frame='void' align='center' valign='top' bordercolor='white'><tr><td colspan='2' height='50' valign='middle' align='center'>imie nazwisko</td><td colspan='2' height='50' valign='middle' align='center'>Numer konta</td><td colspan='2' height='50' valign='middle' align='center'>Saldo</td></tr></table>";
            blok.innerHTML == '';
            blok.innerHTML = zmienna2;
        }

        function strona_logowania() {
            var zmienna1 = "<form id='formularz' name='formularz' action=''><label for='id'>Identyfikator:</label><br><input type='text' name='Identyfikator' id='id' value='' /><br><label for='pass'>HasL‚o:</label><br><input type='password' name='Password' id='pass' value='' /><br><input type='submit' value='Zaloguj siÄ™' onClick='login()'/></form>";
            blok.innerHTML = zmienna1;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="strona_logowania()">
    <div id='blok'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: "it always comes back to first look", it does matter exactly when it comes back ??? what do you do which it s come back ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use an onClick event on a "submit" input element. A simple fix is to replace `type="submit"` by `type="button"`

Comment: Thank you very much, i didn't know it has got that huge meaning. It works fine now.